# SQL Update Join with Where Clause; phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a question about an SQL join. I would like to update a table that runs within a program for a value calculation based on the price development of different accounts (e.g. price development of coal, leather, etc.). In the current version these are about 3000 accounts with an ID, a unique GP number and a value for each year. The problem is that with the new release of the GP values about 900 accounts have been dropped. However, the program must be able to calculate further with these values, since the calculations were assigned to the IDs and not to the GP values. I want to update the GP values for the years 2015, 2016 and 2017...However I don't know how to do it without shooting the IDs (values that are not updated and for which there are calculations will simply get the general price development, but this update can be neglected)

The first table looks like this(tree: gps.gps_alt):

```
INSERT INTO `gps_alt` (`id`, `Nummer`, `Beschreibung`, `Basisjahr`, `depricated`, `1949`, `1950`, `1951`, `1952`, `1953`, `1954`, `1955`, `1956`, `1957`, `1958`, `1959`, `1960`, `1961`, `1962`, `1963`, `1964`, `1965`, `1966`, `1967`, `1968`, `1969`, `1970`, `1971`, `1972`, `1973`, `1974`, `1975`, `1976`, `1977`, `1978`, `1979`, `1980`, `1981`, `1982`, `1983`, `1984`, `1985`, `1986`, `1987`, `1988`, `1989`, `1990`, `1991`, `1992`, `1993`, `1994`, `1995`, `1996`, `1997`, `1998`, `1999`, `2000`, `2001`, `2002`, `2003`, `2004`, `2005`, `2006`, `2007`, `2008`, `2009`, `2010`, `2011`, `2012`, `2013`, `2014`, `2015`, `2016`, `2017`, `2018`, `2019`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES 
(1, 'GP09-05', 'Kohle', 0, 0, '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '100.0', '109.9', '113.0', '114.1', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
(2, 'GP09-06', 'Erdöl und Erdgas', 0, 0, '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '26.2', '27.8', '32.9', '31.0', '30.0', '45.5', '57.5', '52.0', '58.8', '55.0', '75.3', '96.4', '89.8', '113.9', '81.3', '100.0', '118.2', '142.2', '143.4', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
```

The second table looks like this(from this table the values should be entered in 2014,2015,2016 and 2017 of the first table. The tree looks like this: gps.gps_neu):

```
INSERT INTO `gps_neu` (`Nummer`, `2014`, `2015`, `2016`,`2017`) VALUES 
('GP09-052010', '113', '111.3', '110.7','108'), 
('GP09-061010', '130.7', '79.5', '62', '81.1')
```

I want to join now the tables where gps_alt.Nummer = gps_new.Nummer on 2014,2015,2016 and 2017. I already tried the following codes:

```
SELECT gps_alt.2014,
       gps_alt.2015,
       gps_alt.2016,
       gps_alt.2017
  FROM gps.gps_alt
  JOIN LEFT gps_neu.2014,
        gps_neu.2015,
        gps_neu.2016,
        gps_neu.2017
    ON gps.gps_alt.Nummer = gps.gps_neu.Nummer;
```

> ```
> Error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT gps_neu.2014, gps_neu.2015, gps_neu.2016, at line 6
> ```

```
update  gps.gps_alt
  set gps_alt.2014 = gps_neu.2014 ,
   gps_alt.2015 = gps_neu.2015,
   gps_alt.2016 = gps_neu.2016,
   gps_alt.2017 = gps_neu.2017
FROM gps_alt
INNER JOIN gps_neu 
ON gps_alt.Nummer = gps_neu.Nummer;
```

> ```
> With this errormassage: 
> update  gps.gps_alt
>       set gps_alt.2014 = gps_neu.2014 ,
>        gps_alt.2015 = gps_neu.2015,
>        gps_alt.2016 = gps_neu.2016,
>        gps_alt.2017 = gps_neu.2017
>     FROM gps_alt
>     INNER JOIN gps_neu 
>     ON gps_alt.Nummer = gps_neu.Nummer;
> ```

Hope someone can help me, i dont know why this wont work....

Answer (score 0):

I found  the solution.

```
UPDATE  gps_alt a
        INNER JOIN gps_neu b
            ON a.Nummer = b.Nummer
SET     a.2014= b.2014
```